# htaccess converting from zeus to apache rewrite

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I am migrating from a zeus platform to apache and having problems with the following rewrite:

```
/12345-somepage.html
/event.php?ref=12345
```

This is the .htaccess

```
RewriteEngine  on
RewriteRule    ^/([0-9]*)- /event.php?ref=$1 <-- This doesn't work 404 not found
RewriteRule    ^otherpage.htm  index.php?Month=0&Category=otherpage <- This one works
```

This is the exisiting Zeus rewrite rule:

```
match URL into $ with ^/([0-9]*)-
if matched then set URL = /event.php?ref=$1
```

I have verified that the target address works i.e. `/event.php?ref=12345`

Comment: Remove the leading `/` form `RewriteRule ^/(...)`  A `RewriteRule` directive does _not_ begin with `/` like REQUEST_URI does.

Comment: As in `RewriteRule ^([0-9]*)- event.php?ref=$1 [L]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your default `RewriteBase` is `/`, that's why you dont match a leading `/`, set the `RewriteBase` to prevent unexpected behaviour, add modifier `[L]` so Apache stops processing the following rewrites after this matched, add `[QSA]` to append a query string from the original url

This works:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteRule    ^([0-9]+)- /event.php?ref=$1 [L,QSA]
```

my event.php

```
<?php 
echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];
echo "\n";
print_r( $_GET ); 
?>
```

The output

```
# curl -i http://localhost/1234-mypage.html
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Sat, 01 Dec 2012 22:57:28 GMT
Content-Type: text/html

/event.php
Array
(
    [ref] => 1234
)
```